# Broken spark plug

Tags: chevrolet, malibu

How do I remove a spark plug broken off in the engine block of a 2002 Malibu? I successfully removed and changed three spark plugs in my 2002 Chevy Malibu. The fourth one broke off.

Comment: Where did it break? Can you provide a picture of the piece that came out?

Answer (score 1):

Warning try this at your own risk I have heard this works on a ford motor...

Spray a little penetrating oil down around the spark plug to help loosen it. Let sit for about 5 minutes or until a decent amount of the oil evaporates. Put a rag over the spark plug hole to prevent anything from falling in (or possibly fly out).

Quickly crank the engine one cycle to build compression and hopefully pop /loosen the broken piece of the spark plug.

Pull the remaining piece out with a long grabbing utensil or magnet.