# Broken Spark Plug removal

Tags: sparkplugs

I have a 2002 Chevy Venture, that supposedly the Mechanic changed the spark plugs, but when trying to do a tune-up one of the Spark Plugs broke off and the electrode is still in it. I found online a lot of Spark Plug extractors for Fords, but, none for Chevy.

I was wondering, how  can I remove the electrode?

after that I know I can use a Extractor to remove the rest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please post a picture of what you have already removed. I've run across this issue many times, but depending on where it broke off makes a HUGE difference in how difficult it is to remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broken spark plug](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6636/broken-spark-plug)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open for two reasons: 1) the original question (linked by Chenmunka) did not have a selected "answer"; 2) This situation is probably different than that question.

Comment: Without a picture, this question is going to be hard to answer